# Regex - Ignore newlines - match any thing untill end of text or numbers

Tags: regex, vb.net

Hello and thanks for reading. I am Once again playing and trying to learn more about regex. It's a regex question so dont please offer other solutions. I can easily do this with other VB methods. I love every time i improve my regex brain.

Take NEWLIne as a carriage return, i have a textbox in this format.

```
NEWLIne 
NEWLIne 
hello some text
NEWLIne 
some more text
NEWLIne 
NEWLIne
```

I would like to match the data

```
hello some text
NEWLIne 
some more text
```

Ignore every newline until it matches a number or letter, plus a few special chars, ONE newline and proceeds match new text until it reaches a new line break.

Here is what i have `(?i)(?<=\n+)[a-z0-9 :\-\n]+(?=\n+)`

But it's still match every thing. I guess its because of the `\n]+`

Comment: Would you please add the tag for the language you want to use? Looks like VB from context.

Comment: Yes it is visual basic, please for give me. Stack overflow is quite hard for new people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the assumption that a new line is specified by CR, try: `(?im)^.+\n.+$`

`m` in `(?im)` specifies multi-line mode, which should be useful for your needs.

Comment: Hello. I am on my phone so cant test. Does your example take into consideration new lines before and after your edit newline. flag. Am I correct in thinking (?Im) would mean multi and ignore case. Thanks

Comment: `(?im)` does mean Case-Insensitive and Multi-Line respectively.  In multi-line mode, `.` does not match line breaks, and `^` and `$` match the start and end of the line respectively, not the entire string if it has `CR`s.